# PIP Upgrade Permission Denied Windows 10

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

Python 3.6.5 and (currently) pip 9.0.3 trying to upgrade to 10.0.1.

I've checked through various SO threads and nothing quite got me there. When trying to pip install anything and upgrading pip itself, I keep getting this:

**This is when I tried to install Django which then told me I needed to upgrade pip.**

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,

File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs

File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)

File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,

File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)

File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)

File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)

File "c:\program files\python36\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python36\\Lib\\site-packages\\pytz'
```

---

**This is after I tried upgrading pip with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`:**

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 544, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied:** 'c:\\program files\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-9.0.3.dist-info\\description.rst' -> 'C:\\Users\\johns\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-f8ej9z71-uninstall\\program files\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-9.0.3.dist-info\\description.rst'

During handling of the above exception, **another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)

File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\shutil.py", line 559, in move
    os.unlink(src)

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-9.0.3.dist-info\\description.rst'
```

I didn't have this problem on my last computer so I'm kind of confused. I don't understand why I would have a permission error, I'm the admin. I tried `sudo` (but I think that's only mac?). I looked at the repo discussion about how to do it and the pip documentation. And I'm fairly certain I added Python to Path when I installed it.

Thank you for helping me figure this out.

Comment: Ok, so I solved it. If anyone else has this issue, I went to the python folder, right clicked, went to the security tab, and edited the permissions for basically all users are allowed.

Comment: From a security standpoint that is not necessarily the best thing to do. It would be better for you to open your terminal as administrator (as Alvin suggested in his answer). There is a reason those directories were locked down, and it's best you keep it that way so that only people who are supposed to have access to modify those directories (you, for example) are allowed to.

Comment: Fair enough. No one will be using this computer other than me but I'll change it back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open your Command Prompt or Powershell by clicking "Run as administrator".
You can find the steps in this [video](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=run%20as%20administrator%20command%20line&rlz=1C1CHZL_enHK780HK780&oq=Run%20as%20admin&aqs=chrome.2.0j69i57j0l4.3983j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=1).

Comment: I have done this and I'm still getting the same error.